# Build a REST API with no frameworks

Tags: web-services, rest

I want to build a website with a REST API back-end and angularJs as front-end.

I used frameworks all the time when building something like this, but I never paid to much attention to how those frameworks were built(not a lot of free time).

I have started a new project which will be hosted on Google App Engine, I have built few necessary things like:

1. Router Handler
2. Middleware's for checking the Header(content-type) and one which is setting the response writer type, also an errors middleware.
3. Error file which will contain all the error.

I will need to write few more middleware for an authentication system probably.

What other things need to be present in a REST server?

Comment: Better read O'Reilly RESTful Web Services book =) The question seems too broad as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, it depends on what you want to support for your API ;-) I see things like that:

- Routing (routes and sub routes, filter and processing chains)
- Resource path variables (/myresource/{anid}...)
- Query parameters
- Conneg (returned content negociation based on the accept header)
- Support for one or several content types (JSON, XML, ...). A framework like Jackson2 can be useful here (it's painful to implement a complete and efficient bean / structured content conversion)
- Security (basic, token-based, ...)
- Error handling

Perhaps these two links can help you for further hints:

- API Design: https://templth.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/designing-a-web-api/
- API security: https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/implementing-authentication-with-tokens-for-restful-applications/

Hope it helps.
Thierry